# Only Remove SPGroups that Contain a specific Character

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I need to remove groups from a SharePoint site that contain an underscore in the name. I need something like the below code, but I am unable to use .Contains on the collGroups.

Any idea how I can do this?

```
 using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(spsite))
 {
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {         
        SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWeb.SiteGroups;  
        if(collGroups.Contains("_"))  //this doens't work, but I need something like this
        {
            group.Delete();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It inherits `IEnumerable` at a [point in its inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasecollection(v=office.15).aspx), so you should be able to use `.OfType<>().Where()` or a similar linq statement

Comment: ah, yes. thanks. working on a linq statement now!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: here is what I ended up writing, thanks to gunr2171 for pointing me in the right direction!

```
  using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(spsite))
  {
       using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
       {
            var result = (from g in oWeb.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>()
                          where g.Name.Contains("_")
                          select g).ToList();

            foreach (SPGroup group in result)
            {
                SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWeb.SiteGroups;
                collGroups.Remove(group.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Removed " + group.Name);
             }

             Console.WriteLine("Process Complete!");
        }
```